# Creating wrapper over MVC Telerik controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, wrapper, telerik-mvc

I am trying to write wrappers library over telerik controls of MVC.
reason behind this is i can easily change third party control without change in View,Controller.
Is it good idea. 
I am facing problem to hide telrik completely because, they have there own js and return objects.
Am i in correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an abstraction to far. How many view pages are you talking about? Do you have a concrete requirement to be able to change? The odds are you will lose some of the power and just gain a lot of hassle. Probably easier to rewrite the views if is ever required. If you are that worried you probably maybe you should use a non commercial alternative? However it depends what parts you are using I only used the Grid really and we switched our site to DataTables without much issue.

I use Telerik and have never abstracted it but the rest of my architecture is flexible. I don't ever tie Telerik controls directly to a domain entity list etc. I always use a ViewModel mapped from the Domain entity using AutoMapper.

The UI in most business applications is the least significant part and is normally relatively easy to change if you haven't tightly coupled it to your Domain Model.

Comment: Doesn't really seem worth abstracting then. Even if you Telerik components on every page I wouldn't. However it depends on what you are doing and how you are abstracting.

Comment: I am agree with you whatever you have suggested.possibly 200 views can be in my project.I am doing my first project in MVC.NET in this case can you suggest me some good idea to build my project.